# JSQMessages custom cell height does not update

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I need to add two buttons to my bubble. For now I added one in the xib file of the bubble but the height of the bubble does not increase. The only thing I see is this:

[image]

when my xib looks like this:

[image]

The button should be bigger. If i give it a height constraint of 30 for example this happens:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I did in the end was this:

I added my button right below the textview inside the bubble container. I set the height to 30 and I also added this to my code in my View Controller:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout!, heightForCellBottomLabelAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    return 30
}
```